# ABAQUS: homogeneous deformation of a single block

Tags: abaqus

I want to apply a homogeneous deformation on a single block by specifying the displacement field **u** = {ux,uy,uz}, where a bold letter indicates a vector and the terms in the curly brackets are its Cartesian components.

Specifically, the time-dependent displacement field is given by:

ux = A sin(wt) X + q [1-B sin(wt)] sin(2wt) Y

uy = -B sin(wt) Y

uz = C sin(wt) Z

where {X,Y,Z} are the position vector components of a material point, {t} stands for time, and the remaining constants are known numbers.

How can I do that using an input file or directly through ABAQUS?

Thanks!

Comment: this pretty much requires a user subroutine `disp`

Comment: If a Fortran compiler is available, I'd agree with @agentp that `disp` is perfect, being designed for this type of thing. If that isn't an option, things aren't as tidy but not impossible...If so: are the nodal coordinates available before the analysis? Is the load applied to all nodes or a subset?

Comment: Are you running this as a implicit or explicit?